# Javascript problems

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, client-side

First off, let me preface this question by saying that my professor is firmly entrenched in the past. Our last assignment required us to float links on top of pictures.

You might also say that he's insane as in order to test our pages he requires that all functionality (including cookies) be implemented with "client side technology" i.e. not on the server. He uses Firefox to test the pages, so the single blessing is that he doesn't care about cross-browser compatibility.

That being said, I'm having a problem with our latest assignment. We're making a "shopping cart" system using Javascript and cookies to store the items to be purchased. This is fine, except for some reason in my function that adds a new element to the cookie, assigning something to document.cookie doesn't work.

You can find my entire site [here <sup>*.zip file download*</sup>](http://wayne-is.boldlygoingnowhere.org/wayne/webtech/toadsuck/archive.zip) (if there's anything that you wonder, "why on earth would you do that? That's crazy!" - that's either a direct assignment or a way to try and minimize the pain.)

This is my code in question that should be modifying the cookie:

```
var mycookies = new function (){
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    var cookie, values;
    this.items = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < cookies.length; x++){
        if(cookies[x] != ""){
            cookie = cookies[x].split('=')[0].trim()
            values = cookies[x].split('=')[1]
            values = values.split(',');
            if(!this.items[cookie]){
                this.items.push(cookie);
                this[cookie] = new function(){};
            }
            this[cookie].size = values[0];
            this[cookie].qty = parseInt(values[1]);
        }
    }
    this.render = function(){
        var values, cookies = "", cookie;
        for(var x = 0; x < this.items.length; x++){
            cookie = this.items[x];
            values = [this[cookie].size, this[cookie].qty].join(',');
            cookies += cookie + "=" + values + '; ';
        }
        return cookies;    
    }                      
    this.clear = function(){
        for(var x = 0; x < this.items.length; x++){
            delete this[this.items[x]];
        }                  
        this.items = [];
        document.cookie['expires'] = '26 Aug 1984 01:01:01 UTC;';
    }                      
    this.additem = function(){
        var i = document.forms[0].size.selectedIndex;
        if (this.items[page]){
            this[page].size = document.getElementById('size').value;
            this[page].qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
        }                  
        else{              
            this.items.push(page);
            this[page] = new function(){};
            this[page].size = document.getElementById('size').value;
            this[page].qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
        }
        console.log(this.render()); // For use with firebug
        document.cookie = this.render();
        console.log(document.cookie); // For use with firebug
    }
}
```

When I fire this off, firebug provides this output:

```
expires=12 Aug 2001 01:01:01 UTC,NaN; whitec=Small,3;
expires=12 Aug 2001 01:01:01 UTC,NaN
```

Now, I would expect 1) my cookie to have expired (I set the expiration manually through firebug, my parsing added the NaN later, - yet there it stays), and 2) the value for the cookie to be changed to the result of `this.render()`

Other than the obvious fact that client-side cookie behavior is not guaranteed by the w3 spec, am I missing something here? (**EDIT** - what I mean is when the page is client-side, opened as a file - not served by a server) This is really aggravating - I've tried a multitude of different angles, and no "javascript cookie" search or "modify cookies javascript" leads me to anything useful. Any suggestions about how I can fix it?

Or should I just email my professor with a link to the w3 specs and tell him that requiring us to support cookies client side is stupid?

Comment: IMHO, any professor that teaches programming using Javascript is insane. It's a nice teaching language, but since it's an inbrowser language, the development and debugging environments are hell, even with tools like Firebug and Venkman.

Comment: Um... your professor isn't stuck in the past; setting cookies client side is a modern practice. Just ask Facebook. To fix your problem, I suggest reading http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: @Marc First you say that teaching programming using JavaScript is insane. Then you say that JavaScript is a nice teaching language.

Comment: @Wayne JSLint is not happy...

Comment: That deal where you call "split('=')" twice; that's pretty ugly. Also, that `this[cookie] = new function() {}` doesn't really do anything more than just `this[cookie] = {}` would do.

Comment: The language itself is good for learning. Unfortunately, the environment it exists in is BAD for teaching. Not only do you have to learn Javascript, you have to learn HTML, HTTP, etc... as well. Bit much to ask for intro programming. It's like teaching surgery in the middle of a war zone.

Comment: Also, what is "page"?  Where does it get a value from? **edit** oh I found it; it's a **global variable**.  Ick.

Comment: @Marc, it's a web-tech class, but it's pretty schizophrenic. The styles are what you might have seen in 1990, but the tech we use is current stuff. @Pointy, thanks for the info, I'll use that instead.

Comment: @Mark - it's not the cookies that put him in the past - it's everything else (take a look at the page and you'll see, that's how his example looked). When I said client-side I meant that the page was client-side and setting cookies, i.e. `file://yourcomp/folder/page.html`. Unfortunately that's one of those links that Google turned up and sadly failed to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workings of `document.cookie` are not what you apparently think they are. When you **set** a value into the variable, you set **one cookie at a time**. Thus, if you wanted to set all the cookies you're holding in your object, you'd loop through your "items" array and set `document.cookie` successively to each name/value pair (transformed into a "cookieName=cookieValue" string).

This is a fact in all modern browsers. See [this Mozilla documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie) for example.

Other comments on the code, since you were nice enough to post it:

```
        cookie = cookies[x].split('=')[0].trim()
        values = cookies[x].split('=')[1]
```

Better to call "split" just once.

```
            this[cookie] = new function(){};
```

That's essentially equivalent to `this[cookie] = {};` to set the property to a new empty object.

Comment: Ah. Now *that* explains it a lot better than any other resource I've seen. Of course I'm used to filtering APIs for how something works, so it's possible that I missed that information in a post I've read. I'll try this out when I get back, but my guess is this will work.

Comment: This was the perfect link (and explanation). I don't think anything that I read explicitly stated that cookies were set one at a time, and most of them used a path attribute(?) - just looking at the code snippets it seemed like it meant you could add several cookies, and when you added the `expires` cookie it would remove all values. Now I know **this is wrong**. No longer frustrated, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks something may be bad with the dates ?
Try to set expiration time in the far future when setting the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Your programming class sounds a bit strange.

But in my experience, manipulating cookies on the client side is really well supported in the browsers.

Quirksmode has a great article about cookies with some examples of helper functions to set and read cookies: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html